# Toggle & Accordian collapsing together

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, toggle, accordion

I have a bootstrap 3 accordion and I am trying to get it to work with toggle switches.

Currently everything works as it should except that the toggles don't toggle OFF if the panel is collapsed by one of the other accordion panels. Basically I am looking for the toggles to toggle on when a panel is open and toggle off when a panel is collapsed. So that the toggles mimic the accordion. Only the toggle is on if the panel is expanded, and all other toggles and panels would be off / collapsed.

Does anyone know a way to get this to happen?

```js
$("div.panel-heading").on("click",function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is('input:checkbox')) return;
    
    var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
    
    if( !checkbox.prop("checked") ){
        checkbox.prop("checked",true);
    } else {
        checkbox.prop("checked",false);
    }
});
```

```css
 /*---- Toggle Switches ------*/
.checkbox-switch {

/* border: 0.1em solid #444; */
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 2em;
  height: 1em;
 overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  left: 0px;
  float: right;
  

}

.checkbox-switch > input {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox-switch > input ~ .checkbox-switch-inner {
  margin-left: -2.5em;
  -webkit-transition: margin-left 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: margin-left 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: margin-left 0.2s ease;
  transition: margin-left 0.2s ease;
}

.checkbox-switch > input:checked ~ .checkbox-switch-inner {
  margin-left: -1.5em;
}

.checkbox-switch > .checkbox-switch-inner {
  display: block;
  width: 8em;
  height: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.checkbox-switch-inner > * {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
}

.checkbox-switch-inner > .checkbox-switch-on {
  /* background: #31A354; */
  background: #14aa4b;
  width: 3em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.checkbox-switch-inner > .checkbox-switch-off {
  background: #b3b3b3;
  width: 3em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  text-align: right;
}

#ecosystem-collapse .checkbox-switch-inner > .checkbox-switch-on {
 background: #23527C;
}

#reference-collapse .checkbox-switch-inner > .checkbox-switch-on {
 background: #CE691B;
}

.checkbox-switch-inner > .checkbox-switch-handle {
  background: #eee;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  margin-left: -3.5em;
  border: 0.1em solid #999;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
        
    #dataBox {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: white;
 max-width: 350px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 padding: 5px;
 z-index: 9999;
}

        .panel-header {
        cursor: pointer;
        }
/*---- END Toggle Switches ------*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1"><div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        
        Collapsible Group 1
          <label for="00" class="tn-headline">TITLE 1</label>
        
 <label class="checkbox-switch" onclick="javascript:showonlyone('nutlayer1');toggleDiv('nutlayer1');"> <!-- The onclick attribute is required by iOS -->
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio tn-switch" id="00" checked="checked"/>
    <span class="checkbox-switch-inner">
      <span class="checkbox-switch-on"></span>
       <span class="checkbox-switch-off"></span>
       <span class="checkbox-switch-handle"></span>
   </span>
 </label>
      </h4>
    </div></a>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
      minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2"><div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        
        Collapsible Group 2
          <label for="01" class="tsin-headline">TITLE 2</label>
    
  
   
 <label class="checkbox-switch" onclick> <!-- The onclick attribute is required by iOS -->
    <input class="radio tsin-switch" type="checkbox" id="01" >
    <span class="checkbox-switch-inner">
      <span class="checkbox-switch-on"></span>
       <span class="checkbox-switch-off"></span>
       <span class="checkbox-switch-handle"></span>
   </span>
 </label>
      </h4>
        </div></a>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
      minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3"><div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        
        Collapsible Group 3<label for="01" class="tsin-headline">TITLE 3</label>
          <label class="checkbox-switch" onclick> <!-- The onclick attribute is required by iOS -->
    <input class="radio tsin-switch" type="checkbox" id="01" >
    <span class="checkbox-switch-inner">
      <span class="checkbox-switch-on"></span>
       <span class="checkbox-switch-off"></span>
       <span class="checkbox-switch-handle"></span>
   </span>
 </label>
      </h4>
    </div></a>
    <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
      minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: whatever is your requirement, everything is present in the fiddle you added, then what are you asking for additionally!! unclear!!

Comment: You need to refer to the previously selected panel so when a new panel is clicked the previous checkbox can toggle off.

Comment: Everything is working EXCEPT when you open a second panel, and the other open panel collapses, the toggle switch doesn't turn off. I am unsure how to target the toggle to turn off when a panel is collapsed from another panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example :https://jsfiddle.net/3yjt4Lah/3/

```
$("div.panel-heading").on("click",function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is('input:checkbox')) return;

    $("#accordion").each(function(){
        var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
      checkbox.prop("checked",false);
    })
    var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
    if( !checkbox.prop("checked") ){
        checkbox.prop("checked",true);
    } else {
        checkbox.prop("checked",false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome! That did the trick! Thank you so much for your help. I was making this way more difficult than it needed to be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find that last panel clicked, so when a new panel is clicked the previous checkbox will clear:

```
var lastPanel = $("div.panel-heading, #collapse1"); //this is the default panel
$("div.panel-heading").on("click",function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is('input:checkbox')) return;

    var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");

    if(lastPanel && target !== lastPanel)
        lastPanel.find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked",false);

    if( !checkbox.prop("checked") ){
        checkbox.prop("checked",true);
    } else {
        checkbox.prop("checked",false);
    }
    lastPanel = target;
});
```

See [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/3yjt4Lah/4/)